# Draw a points in line plot with R + ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Usually I create a plot like this in Excel:

[image]

I'm exploring moving this to ggplot, however among the geoms I don't see one that can be used, any ideas on how to replicate this with R and ggplot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = 1, label= label))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,100))+
  geom_segment(x = 0, xend = 100, y = 1, yend = 1, color = "blue")+
  geom_segment(x = 0, xend = 0, y = 0.99, yend = 1.01, color = "blue")+
  geom_segment(x = 100, xend = 100, y = 0.99, yend = 1.01, color = "blue")+
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 3)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0.99, yend = 1.01),color = "red")+
  ylim(0.9,1.1)+
  geom_text(aes(y = 1.025))+
  geom_text(aes(y = 0.975, label = paste(x,"%", sep = "")))+
  annotate(geom= "text",label = 0, y = 0.975, x = 0)+
  annotate(geom = "text", label = 100, y = 0.975, x = 100)+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

**Reproducible data**

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(10,25,65),
                 label = c("Variable1","Variable2","Variable3"))
```

Comment: Was not aware of geom_segment + geom_point combine with theme_void!

Comment: You're welcome ;). I'm still having trouble to found something that I can't plot with `ggplot2`.

Comment: I see... the plot is identical!